# Android Image Rotation: Ending it at a random position

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to rotate an image and i want it to stop rotating at a random position. I have the following code. The image rotates infinitely. I'm having problems to stop it at a random position.

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f,360f,55f,55f);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(80);

// Start animating the image

iv.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: When do you want to stop it? On press of something?

Comment: it starts on onClick, but i need to stop it after some time at a random position without pressing something.

Comment: Then change your `repeatCount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this parameter as per your requirement

```
anim.setRepeatCount(50);
```

The following line in your code makes the anim run infinitely.

```
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE)
```

Change your `RotateAnimation` as

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f,generateRandomNumber(),55f,55f);
anim.setFillAfter(true);

public float generateRandomNumber() {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((360 - 0) + 1);

    return (float)randomNum;
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, but it stops at the same position from where it starts

Comment: @user3732656 If this is working then kindly select this as the answer by clicking the tick mark. :)

Comment: no its giving the same result. when the animation stops, the image is at the same position as it was before

Comment: @user3732656 Then kindly select this as the answer